# Using an unsupported package (covRobust) in R (v2.15) on MacOSX (10.8)

Tags: macos, r

This is my first time posting, but definitely not my first time on this board!

I am trying to use an R script that someone else wrote as I am not very proficient in programming yet and its a very long script. It calls on the package 'covRobust' which appears to no longer be supported by R and is not available in the CRAN repositories. I can download the package at http://cran.open-source-solution.org/src/contrib/Archive/covRobust/. While I believe I installed the package correctly in my local library, I get this error when I type library(covRobust) in the R terminal:

Error: package 'covRobust' was built before R 2.10.0: please re-install it.

I've tried using an older version of R, but they don't appear to be compatible with MacOSX 10.8.

I'm new to R and have tried searching for a package that does the same thing (nearest neighbor variance estimation), but have been unsuccessful there as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When I download that package in source format and install with the GUI Package Installer from a 'local source package' I get no errors. It does not appear to even require the XCode facilities for compilation. It also appears to load without error. I am using R64.app, so I do not think this is a 32 bit versus 64 bit issue. Using R 2.15.2 with OSX 10.6.8.